# android registering to content observer from a service

Tags: android, service, android-contentprovider

I am just trying to understand the android services and content observer.

So I tried a program where my activity starts a service and within service I register to CONTACTS URI to get notified when the contacts db changes.

I rum my program and I can see this service coming under applications -> running services.
Now I try to add a contact and my observer is getting notified.
If I edit contact again , its not getting notified. Its only the first time after running my program if I edit contacts , the content observer get notified
Please see my code details below

Mainactivity to start the service :

```
public class ContactChangeOberverServiceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("Start","Service");
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

the service :

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        ContactObserverActivity observer = new ContactObserverActivity(new Handler());
        observer.register(getApplicationContext());
        return  super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the observer is :

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // super.onChange(selfChange);
    Log.e(TAG, "Onchange Called");
    //MainActivity.takeContactBackup();
    Intent intent = new Intent (ctx,ContactsExtractorActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
}

/ TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void register(Context ctx) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Registering");
    this.ctx = ctx;
    curval = ctx.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
            null);
    curval.registerContentObserver(new ContactObserverActivity(
            new Handler()));
    Log.e(TAG, "Registered");
}
```

Please help me to understand this behavior and the fix for it.Thank you.

Comment: i have same problem did you fixed this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

using this URI:

> ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI

worked for me!